# How do I append a dictionary as another value to an existing dictionary key

Tags: python

I currently have a nested dictionary, with a dictionary as a value

I want to add another dictionary as SECOND item to the same key
so that it looks something like this:

```
{'mykey1': {'-11111': 0, 'A': 1}, {Second dictionary}, ...}
```

"append" doesn't work and "update" replaces the value.

Do I need something like a list of dictionaries for the value?

```
{'mykey1': [{'-11111': 0, 'A': 1}, {'-11111': 201910, 'A': 201910}] ,
 'mykey2': [{'-11111': 0, 'A': 1}, {'-11111': 201909, 'A': 201910}]}
```

In which case:
a) How do I append the second dictionary element to each key in the existing dict?
b) How do I access that second dictionary? 
thanks

Comment: Yes, you need a list (or a tuple) of dictionaries as value. You cannot have two values for a key.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need a list or a tuple for your Task. try to store the two dictionaries in a list and then assign it to the wrapper dictionary

```
ls = [{'-11111': 0, 'A': 1},{'-11111': 201910, 'A': 201910} ]

dic = {}
dic["myKey1"] = ls
```

or simply:

```
ls = [{'-11111': 0, 'A': 1},{'-11111': 201910, 'A': 201910} ]

dic = {"mykey": ls}
print(dic)  # {'mykey': [{'-11111': 0, 'A': 1}, {'-11111': 201910, 'A': 201910}]}
```

Comment: @MichaelK can you please consider accepting the answer if it helped you?

Comment: Hey man, this really helped me out in a jam.  Appreciate your taking the time to answer this.

Answer (score 2):

you just need to build each object in turn.

```
first_dict{key}.update(list(first_dict{key}, {second_dict}.
```

will take the existing value from the dictionary for a given key and replace it with a list of that value plus another dictionary, `second_dict`

It isn't totally clear to me what how you want to structure your data.

If you built a little example of exactly what you want the data to be structured as, it'll be easier to give an exact answer.